# Selector for more than one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In my web application I have checkboxes for showing and hiding windows. This is done by changing the class of the elements when a checkbox i checked.

So far I wrote this with succes.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#field').change(function(){
                    if(this.checked) {
                        $('.field').fadeIn('slow');
                        $('.field').addClass('areavisible');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.field').fadeOut('slow');
                        $('.field').removeClass('areavisible');
                    }
                });
            });
```

The problem is that the .fadeIn should only work on class .field if the element also has class .typevisible

Comment: I prefer the original title, as it was explaining the intent, not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the selector :

```
$('.field.typevisible').fadeIn('slow');
```

Only elements having both classes will fade in.